# Typescript "cannot find module <module>" error using ES6 modules

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a file in `src/shared/components/A.tsx` that does `import B from 'components/B'` (`src/shared/components/B.tsx`)

Typescript gives me an error `cannot find module 'components/B'`

This is my `tsconfig.json` file which is in the root directory:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "./dist/",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "module": "es6",
      "target": "es6",
      "jsx": "react",
      "allowJs": true,
      "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "include": [
      "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
  ],
  "baseUrl": ".",
  "paths": {
      "*": [
        "*",
        "src/shared/*" //this doesn't seem to work
      ]
  }
}
```

My understanding from https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html is that it will try to find `./components/B` first, which does not exist, then go into `<baseUrl>/src/shared/components/B`, which is where the file exists, so I'm not sure why I'm still seeing an error.

Comment: Out of curiosity - if you rename the `.jsx` file to a `.js` file, does that work? If you explicitly import with `.jsx` as a suffix, does that fix it?

Comment: It worked before I ported to typescript and if I change the file extension Typescript won't throw errors in the file. However, module B has errors in the code which would prevent it from compiling... Does typescript attempt to compile modules that are imported into a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this was silly, `paths` / `baseUrl` belong inside `compilerOptions`.